# Filtrar por id en livewire - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla (clients_credits) que guarda todos los registros y estos registros pertenecen a un cliente de la tabla (clients), hasta ahora todo bien.

Lo que quiero lograr es que filtro el id de cliente para que me muestre solo los creditos que corresponden a un cliente, pero eso no lo encuentro ya que me muestra todos los registros.

**Rutas**

```
Route::get('/clientes/{id}/creditos', [ClientCreditController::class, 'show'])->name('clientes-creditos-index');
```

Mi vista principal se administra a través de un controlador, dentro de mi archivo Blade tengo un componente Livewire que me lleva a la tabla donde se muestran todos los registros.

**client-credit.blade.php**

```
<x-app-layout>
    @livewire('client-credit-show', ['id' => $client], key($client->id))
</x-app-layout>
```

El componente livewire tiene filtrado de fechas

**clientecreditshow.php**

```
public $search, $client, $userid, $report, $reportType, $dateFrom, $dateTo;
public $sort = 'id';
public $direction = 'desc';

public function mount(){
    $this->userid = 0;
    $this->client = 0;
    $this->report = [];
    $this->reportType = 0;
}

public function render()
{
    $this->ReportByDate();
    $users = User::all();   
    return view('livewire.client-credit-show', compact('users'));
}


public function ReportByDate() {
    if ($this->reportType == 0) {
        $from = Carbon::parse(Carbon::createFromDate(1999, 01, 01))->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
        $to = Carbon::parse(Carbon::createFromDate(2080, 12, 31))->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
    } else {
        $from = Carbon::parse($this->dateFrom)->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
        $to = Carbon::parse($this->dateTo)->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
    }
    if ($this->reportType == 1 && ($this->dateFrom == '' || $this->dateTo == '')) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->userid == 0) {
        $this->report = ClientCredit::join('users', 'users.id', 'clients_credits.user_id')
                                    ->select('clients_credits.*', 'users.name')
                                    ->where('clients_credits.date', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                                    ->whereBetween('clients_credits.date', [$from, $to])
                                    ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
                                    ->get();
    } else {
        $report = ClientCredit::join('users', 'users.id', 'clients_credits.user_id')
                                    ->select('clients_credits.*', 'users.name')
                                    ->whereBetween('clients_credits.date', [$from, $to])
                                    ->where('user_id', $this->userid)
                                    ->get();
    }
}
```

}

**ClientCreditController**

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);

    return view('livewire.client-credit', compact('client'));
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que me muestre solo los créditos correspondientes a un cliente? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema es que estás obteniendo todos los usuarios con el siguiente comando dentro de `render`

```
$users = User::all();
```

Si deseas filtrar por usuario podrías utilizar el método `where()` o `when()` para hacerlo

Veo que tienes una variable `$userid` que puedes utilizar para filtrar de la siguiente forma

Con `where()`, si siempre vas a filtrar por algún usuario

```
$users = User::query()
->where('id', 'like', '%'.$this->userid.'%');
```

Con `when()`, en caso de que el filtro pueda estar vacío

```
$users = User::query()
->when($this->userid, fn($query, $search) => $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no busco filtrar por usuario, sino por el cliente quien se le hizo "click" por ejemplo la url para ver la tabla de clientes es **ejemplo.test/clientes** le doy click a un cliente y me lleva a la url **ejemplo.test/clientes/15/creditos** siendo 15 el id del cliente seleccionado, el archivo blade que se encarga de mostrarme la vista tiene un componente de Livewire que lo que debe de ser es tomar el numero 15 para filtrar y mostrarme unicamente los creditos correspondientes a ese cliente, pero me devuelve todos :(

Comment: Ya veo, pero con tu ruta estás llamando `ClientCreditController` y al método `show()` ¿Puedes agregar lo que tienes en el método `show()` de `ClientCreditController`?

Comment: ya edite la publicacion colocando lo que tengo en el controlador